# Using Google Analytics to determine whether paid media visitors subsequently return

Tags: google-analytics, advertising, visitors

I'd like to be able to find out whether I am driving returning visits to my site through paid media. E.g. what percentage of people who initially visited for the first time through an advert *now* return organically?

For first time visitors from paid sources (Display, CPC etc):

- Return visit frequency
- % who return

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you *should* be able to achieve this via a sequence segment.

If you base the sequence on Users rather than Sessions, it will search across sessions for the same User, and match the sequence steps, even if they happen in seperate sessions.

For example:
Step 1 should be based on the Medium (cpc) and User Type New Visitor
Step 2 Medium (organic) and User Type Returning Visitor
[image: sequence segment example]

Answer (score 0):

This question has also been asked [in the Google Product Fourms](https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/Z99cTUcMDAo/z09VHW87IcUJ).   The only answer there states that conversions are attributed back to the campaign for six months for returning visitors.  Unfortunately, it doesn't give any way to get the reports about the number of returning visitors.

There do appear to be some third party analytics packages and addons to Google Analytics that will do this analysis.   [This one from SkyGlue](http://www.skyglue.com/tutorials/create-your-own-reports/) looks very promising:

[image]